# Debug.Print shows me a value, but 'If not' wouldn't work with this value

Tags: vba, if-statement, powerpoint

I am totally baffled. Can't find a solution.
I ask for the value of a shape:

```
? ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom
```

Answer:  `11.29354`

I write a routine:

```
If Not oshp.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 11.29354 Then
    TellMe = "MarginBottom =" & oshp.TextFrame.MarginBottom & " but not 11.29354" 
End If
```

The routine won't work. I claims the shape's MarginBottom has not the value, but in the same moment it gives me the value as a result.

That would mean the value is not the value. Any experienced guy has background info on this?

Comment: In the routine, what is shown for `oshp.TextFrame.MarginBottom` if not 11.29354?  If you then do `?TellMe` in the Immediate window, what does it print out?  Can you view this shape `oshp` in the Locals window?  Is it possible that your `Selection.ShapeRange` is not the same as `oShp`?

Comment: Hey David.- It showed me the weird "Margin.Bottom = 11.29354 but not 11.29534" -- that's how I understood somethings fishy here. Fortunately CStr did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be rounding, you can test in the immediate window thus:

First assign the value:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 11.23456789
```

Then retrieve it:

```
? ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom
 11.23457
```

It's changed, test it against the new value and the assigned value:

```
? ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 11.23456789
False
? ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 11.23457
False
```

Neither works, convert to string and test:

```
? CStr(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.MarginBottom) = "11.23457"
True
```

I don't know if you're able to test on a string value, but this comparison will work.

Comment: PERFEKT! Thank you so much! Always will use CStr now with values like that.